# php: want to create image by text in browser using ajax or onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

want to create image using text.

I am generating text's from csv file.
then I want to create image by clicking on one of the text.
I am using ajax to set image as per click.
but I am not getting idea, that what to return to set image for display
please suggest me changes or script to implement it.
My Code Snippet:

index.php:-

```
<style>
    .excrec {
        margin: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<?php

$file_path =  'csvfile.csv';
if (($handle = fopen($file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i=0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

         if(empty($data)){ continue; }  

         if($i>0){

             $excRec = $data[0].', '.$data[1].', '.$data[2];
             echo '<div id='.$i.' class="excrec">'.$excRec.'</div>';                 
         }    
         $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}else{
    echo "Oops! something went wrong";
}
?>

<br><br>
<img src="" id="showimg">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('click','.excrec',function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault();

        var text = $(this).html();
        $('#showimg').attr("src", "text2img.php?text=" + text);
    });
</script>
```

txt2img.php:-

```
 <?php
  $text = $_GET['text'];

  $recimg = imagecreate(200, 80);
  $background  = imagecolorallocate($recimg, 400, 40, 45);
  $text_colour = imagecolorallocate($recimg, 140, 140, 140);
  imagestring($recimg, 4, 30, 25, $text, $text_colour);
  imagesetthickness($recimg, 5);

  header("Content-type: image/png");
  imagepng($recimg);
  imagecolordeallocate($text_color);
  imagecolordeallocate($background); 
  imagedestroy($recimg);

  //what we return to set image
?>
```

both files are in same folder including csv file..

please suggest me for commented lines..

Comment: You can make this much easier on yourself if you send the text as GET param instead and use `$('#showing').attr("src", "text2img.php?text=" + text);`

Comment: will you please write some code snippet for me in answer.. i tried with following code, but didn't work.. jQuery(document).on('click','.excrec',function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault();

        var text = $(this).html();
        $('#showing').attr("src", "text2img.php?text=" + text);
    });

Comment: You also have to change `$text = $_POST['text'];` to `$text = $_GET['text'];`. (also, if you change your code, please put it in the question)

Comment: please check the edits

Comment: Typo: `#showing` has to be `#showimg`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q6cv2xfa/

Comment: yes, I updated that one also, but now its showing blank image & "text2img.php?text=Suresh, Shinde, MCS" in image src

Comment: @ChrisG you have used "https://via.placeholder.com".. can we do it from our code

Comment: Uh, sure, I guess? Depends on what you're after: https://placeholder.com/

Comment: working through placehoder.com.. thanks